# SCSS Styling Not Working...Z-Index Issue?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to configure my header in SCSS to have everything display like this:
[image]

I am getting this however:
[image]

The container on the left is pushing the search field all the way to the right.  I am sure it is a  issue in the html or a position/z-index issue in the scss, but I am not able to get it to work properly.

Here is the html:

```
      <div>
      <input *ngIf="!(isMobile$ | async) && (isOnline$ | async)"
      #filterTextInput
      id="filter-text-input"
      class="gfs-numeric-input"
      type="text"
      [value]="itemFilterText$ | async"
      autocomplete="off"
      placeholder="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}"
      attr.aria-label="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}"
      >
      <mat-icon class="search-icon" svgIcon="search-icon"></mat-icon>
      </div>
```

and here is my scss:

```
    .worksheet-name-container {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
```

.worksheet-name-container is the the leftmost property that says "Untitled" and "Items"

```
.search-input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 600px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  padding: 2px 8px 2px 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fafafa, #f3f3f3);
}

.search-icon {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 12px;
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `display: absolute;` Is this a typo or am I about to learn something new?

Comment: @RobMoll I was just going to test this code, I would have never found that. ✌

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.  Not sure where it came from.  Obviously it should say 'position'.  It still does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in a simpler way, just using Flex-box or Grid, see the example below using Flex-box.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <span>Your Title</span>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="search" name="search" id="js-search" placeholder="Search">
        <button>My Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scss:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;

  span {
    width: fit-content;
  }

  .wrapper {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    place-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 2rem;
   }
}
```

Just add the necessary remaining style now to the elements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why does not work? Have any limitations, can't you use some properties that were used in my example? @rskybsn